# Ipad/Iphone - Disable address bar in public use

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, safari

I have two ipads that I want to use in public. The problem I'm having is that I don't want people to be able to change the url in safari that is showing a webpage. I don't want to limit the screen either. Is it possible to disable the usage of the address bar on safari in some way?

Comment: Is there any chance you could use Apple Developer Tools and Xcode? If so, you can use a WebView in a plain App with nothing in it but the webview.

Comment: @LlogariCasas - That's a solution that I will take with me for future use!. However this is not possible right now I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to open the webpage in Safari, and then save to home screen. Afterwards, open the webpage saved on home screen. You will find you can't see the address bar.

Comment: Yes. However any links to the same domain will popup a new window in safari.